# Suggestions on troubleshooting QueryDefs in Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access seems to hang when it executes a specific querydef. If I pause the code before it executes, manaually run the querydef and then start the code after it calls for the querydef it runs fine. There is something with Access calling the querydef that just kills it's performance.

The code itself is and has been fine for years. This seems to be a recent development...

Here's the code:

```
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryPostTeachers")
qdf.Parameters("currentPostID") = lPostID
qdf.Execute dbSeeChanges + dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Have you already tried a "Comapct and Repair" of the MDB file?

Comment: Yeah that's been done. This is an application and we deploy it all over. Different servers, databases, etc. The problems are attached to the database and aren't machine specific.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you try qdf.Execute without the options?

Comment: I'm not sure you need dbSeeChanges. Have you tried it with just dbFailOnError? That is, I use dbSeeChanges for opening recordsets, but I've never used it for executing DML SQL.

Comment: Another things is that I would never bother with using a QueryDef for this, but I'd write the SQL with the relevant WHERE clause on the fly. The benefits of doing it your way are very slim, and in the real world, not significant.

Comment: Could there be a conflict with some other process using the same datasource and taking up server resources? Or perhaps the database has grown in size?

Comment: @David, @Hans - I haven't tried removing the options. I'll try that
@Power - I've added msgbox before and after the query and letting it sit for several minutes to make sure that wasn't the case. The db has grown significantly, but the query executes fine when not called in Access. All it does is populate a table in access, so I've run it manually and then let access finish. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

JetShowPlan may help.

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188211%28office.10%29.aspx